# How to create a schema for a combination of values that needs to be unique

Tags: postgresql, schema, relational-theory

How would I create a schema for the following data:

```
Dimension A

Attribute X, Attribute Y
positive   , positive    => Description 1
positive   , negative    => Description 2
negative   , positive    => Description 3
negative   , negative    => Description 4

Dimension B

Attribute Z, Attribute W
positive   , positive    => Description 5
positive   , negative    => Description 6
negative   , positive    => Description 7
negative   , negative    => Description 8
```

It should not be possible for a combination of attributes to result in multiple outcomes.

Is there a way to structure this that would allow for more dimensions to be created without creating new tables? The created dimensions would have different attributes with different names but those attributes would always have as values either positive or negative.

I'm hoping to accomplish this in postgres.

Comment: I failed to understand the question. It's unclear, what "outcome" is supposed to mean for a relational design.

Comment: To try to expand @Erwin's comment (which I agree with): If `X, Y` are independent of `Z, W`, how can you combine them and not get multiple `Outcome`s? -- that is, both a `2` and a `7`, say. Not that I understand what "combination of attributes" could mean here. Does "the number of dimensions should be dynamic" mean you might have dimensions `C, D, E, ...`? Then what Attributes would they have? Is it that each Dimension has two Attributes, and their names don't matter? They could just be `Left, Right` (?)

Comment: I did a poor job simplifying what's a bigger domain. The original domain is about a person's traits, which could be personality or other dimensions and the outcomes are what would be called someone with a combination of those traits.

I edited the original questions to try to make it more clearer, thanks for taking the time to try to understand it.

Comment: "The created dimensions would have different attributes with different names" then they'd have to be as extra attributes in your existing tables -- in which case they'd have to be there all the time, not somehow "created" dynamically; or they'd be in other/extra tables -- which doesn't change (or help with) the nature of the problem. " those attributes would always have as values either positive or negative." -- sure the 'Attributes' are in effect type Boolean, so what? Is it possible some 'Dimension' might have more than two 'Attribute's?

Comment: " the outcomes are what would be called someone with a combination of those traits." so this is for example the 'Five-factor model' of personality; the outcomes (Description) something like 'High in Consciousness' or 'Medium-to-low in Agreeableness' ?? I'm just wildly guessing here. Perhaps you could give some sample data for one of the 'Dimensions'. (Beware each of those Factors has a great deal more than two indicators by which they're assessed.) And the whole idea of calling them 'Factor's or 'Dimension's is they're orthogonal: there's a rating against each 'Factor' independently.

Comment: Your terminology does not clarify things for me. Try examples. Show a table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) and some sample values. Show what's supposed to be allowed or not.